# AS3: change Font in Radio button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

How can I change font used in Radio Button that existing in default components of flash professional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the font of your `RadioButton` component label, you can use the [`RadioButton.setStyle()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/core/UIComponent.html#setStyle()) function to set the [`TextFormat`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html) which will be applied to the label (a TextField object) of the `RadioButton` component.

For that, you can do like this for example :

```
var text_format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    text_format.font = 'Verdana';
    text_format.color = 0xff0000;

RadioButton(radio_button).setStyle('textFormat', text_format);
```

you can also apply that directly to the label using the `RadioButton.textField` property which return the TextField object :

```
RadioButton(radio_button).textField.setTextFormat(text_format);
```

Hope that can help.